# jquery :nth-of-type acting quirky

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery `nth-of-type` to make divs slide up and down ( `slideToggle()` and `click()` ). The problem is that when I try clicking one of the things to open the tabs, they don't open.

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs-wrapper">
    <div class="op">Tab One</div>
    <div class="op">Tab Two</div>
    <div class="op">Tab Three</div>
    <div class="tab">Pattern One</div>
    <div class="tab">Pattern One</div>
    <div class="tab">Pattern One</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.tab').hide();
$('.op:nth-of-type(1)').click(function(){
    $('.tab:nth-of-type(1)').slideToggle();
});
$('.op:nth-of-type(2)').click(function(){
    $('.tab:nth-of-type(2)').slideToggle();
});
$('.op:nth-of-type(3)').click(function(){
    $('.tab:nth-of-type(3)').slideToggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/rm9mkoau/4/)

Comment: To get matches, add `3` to each of the `.tab:nth-of-type`s i.e. _4_, _5_, _6_ (but this requires knowing you've got 3 tabs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class pays attention only to the element type. None of your "tab" elements are the first, second, or third `<div>` in their container, so none match the selector.

You could, I think, do this:

```
$('.op:nth-of-type(3n+1)').click(function(){
    $('.tab:nth-of-type(3n+1)').slideToggle();
});
```

You'd have to make sure that the `3` was updated when you add/remove a tab of course.

Alternatively you could do this:

```
$(".op").click(function() {
  $(".tab").eq($(this).index()).slideToggle();
});
```

Then you'd just need to set up one handler.

Comment: So instead I should use `$('#tabs-wrapper:nth-of-type(1)');` and so on?

Comment: @yak613 well, you could do that, or you could take into account the presence of the 3 "op" elements. Personally I'd go for a more explicit relationship between the clickable elements and the tabs.

Comment: It's not clear why this'd be downvoted; there's really not much more to say about why the selector matches nothing.

Comment: Using `$('#tabs-wrapper:nth-of-type(1)');` isn't working: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/rm9mkoau/5/)

Comment: @yak613 I put a couple other ideas in the answer; I'm working on a sample jsfiddle too :)

Comment: All of the answers _work_, but I can only mark one solved. =)

Answer (score 1):

To complete Pointy's answer with an example:

```
$('.tab').hide();
$('.op:nth-of-type(1)').click(function(){
  $('div:nth-of-type(4)').slideToggle();
});
$('.op:nth-of-type(2)').click(function(){
  $('div:nth-of-type(5)').slideToggle();
});
$('.op:nth-of-type(3)').click(function(){
   $('div:nth-of-type(6)').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: It's working, but better are solutions where we don't need to change script when we want to add another tab :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:eq` selector as well. Then elements will be count as expected, 0-2 (indexed from 0).

```
$('.tab').hide();
$('.op:eq(0)').click(function(){
    $('.tab:eq(0)').slideToggle();
});
$('.op:eq(1)').click(function(){
    $('.tab:eq(1)').slideToggle();
});
$('.op:eq(2)').click(function(){
    $('.tab:eq(2)').slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rm9mkoau/6/

Or shortly, not depending on elements number.

```
$('.tab').hide();
$('.op').click(function(){
    $('.tab:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rm9mkoau/8/

Answer (score 1):

You have the explanation in pointy's answer, but to add a bit of variation to the solutions so far, you could try this approach:

```
$('.op').click(function() {
  var pos = $(this).parent().indexOf($(this));
  $('.tab').eq(pos).slideToggle();
});
```

This could be condensed, but I've left it in a more readable form so you can get a grip of what it's doing.

It 'says': "Get me the position of this clicked 'op' element amongst all of the other elements in the parent of it. Get all of the 'tab' elements, and slideToggle the tab element that corresponds to the position of the 'op' element clicked."

**NOTE: This will target any `.op` and `.tab` elements in your mark-up, you may choose to make it more specific.**

Answer (score 1):

The `nth-of-type` selector discriminates based solely on the element name - not class.

> The :nth-of-type(an+b) pseudo-class notation represents an element
>   that has an+b-1 siblings with the same expanded element name before it
>   in the document tree, for any zero or positive integer value of n, and
>   has a parent element.
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo

One alternative here is to use the [jQuery `:eq` selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
$('.tab').hide();
$('.op:eq(0)').click(function(){
    $('.tab:eq(0)').slideToggle();
});
$('.op:eq(1)').click(function(){
    $('.tab:eq(1)').slideToggle();
});
$('.op:eq(2)').click(function(){
    $('.tab:eq(2)').slideToggle();
});
```

Although a far more elegant solution would be to use `jQuery.index` to select the `.tab` with the same index as the clicked `.op`.

```
$('#tabs-wrapper').on('click', '.op', function(){
    var $t = $(this), $tab;
    $tab = $t.siblings('.tab').eq($t.index());
    $tab.slideToggle();
});
```